# Undeclared type adter 'swift build'

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift-package-manager

I'm trying to integrate my library with the Swift Package Manager. 
After running `swift build` it successfully downloads the dependency, but then it also gives me the following error:

```
/Users/nikita/Documents/Projects/Projects/TestFramezilla/test/Packages/Framezilla-0.1.1/Sources/UIView+Installer.swift:14:18: error: use of undeclared type 'UIView'
public extension UIView {
                 ^~~~~~
/Users/nikita/Documents/Projects/Projects/TestFramezilla/test/Packages/Framezilla-0.1.1/Sources/UIView+Installer.swift:29:18: error: use of undeclared type 'UIView'
public extension UIView {
                 ^~~~~~
/Users/nikita/Documents/Projects/Projects/TestFramezilla/test/Packages/Framezilla-0.1.1/Sources/UIView+Relations.swift:27:11: error: use of undeclared type 'UIView'
extension UIView {
          ^~~~~~
/Users/nikita/Documents/Projects/Projects/TestFramezilla/test/Packages/Framezilla-0.1.1/Sources/UIView+Relations.swift:39:18: error: use of undeclared type 'UIView'
public extension UIView {
```

Cocoapods and Carthage work fine. I really spent a lot of hours and can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to build an iOS framework. The package manager itself does not currently support directly targeting other platforms than the one it is running on (macOS in this case).

If you want to build for iOS, you will have to do so by generating an Xcode project and building from that (`swift package generate-xcodeproj`). You may still need to manually modify the generated project to change it to use the iOS SDK.